# time complexity of the recurrence equation

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence

Running time of the recurrence equation  Cn = C(n/2) + 1 , C1 = 1.

What is the time complexity of it?

I am thinking O(logn) because it does not matter with (+1) because n > 1 in Big O notation. if n = 0, it would be just O(1). I am pretty confused. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the time complexity of **C<sub>n</sub> = C<sub>n/2</sub> + 1** is **`O(logn)`** using [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). Btw its the equation of [Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

From master method:

**T<sub>n</sub> = aT<sub>n/b</sub> + F<sub>n</sub>**

There are following three cases:

1. If f(n) = O(n<sup>c</sup>) where c < <sup>Log<sub>b</sub>a</sup> then T(n) = O(n<sup>Log<sub>b</sub>a</sup>)
2. If f(n) = O(n<sup>c</sup>) where c = <sup>Log<sub>b</sub>a</sup> then T(n) = O(n<sup>Log<sub>b</sub>a</sup>*Logn)
3. If f(n) = O(n<sup>c</sup>) where c > <sup>Log<sub>b</sub>a</sup> then T(n) = O(f(n))

In your case:
`a = 1`, `b = 2`

So n<sup>Log<sub>b</sub>a</sup> = n<sup>Log<sub>2</sub>1</sup> = n<sup>0</sup> = 1

Also f(n) = O(1). So n<sup>Log<sub>b</sub>a</sup> = c (Case 2)

Therefore, T(n) = O(n<sup>Log<sub>b</sub>a</sup>*Logn) = Θ(n<sup>0</sup>*Logn) = **O(Logn)**